# Moving an image when clicked on by the mouse in a C# XNA game

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I need to have an image move only when it is clicked on by the mouse.

I have this for the movement:

```
if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
    previousMouseState.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    xpos = rnd.Next(windowWidth - texture.Width);
    ypos = rnd.Next(windowHeight - texture.Height);
}

previousMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
```

But I need some sort of compound `if` logic to make it so it only moves if the texture is clicked on.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your `texture` object isn't just a `Texture2D`.

When drawing a sprite, you have both position and size. Something like this should work:

```
var currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

if (currentMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
previousMouseState.LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(currentMouseState.X,currentMouseState.Y);

    mousePosition-=sprite.Position;

    /// .Bounds is a property of Texture2D, and returns a Rectangle() struct
    var spriteWasClicked = sprite.Bounds.Contains(mousePosition.X,mousePosition.Y);

    if(spriteWasClicked)
    {
        xpos = rnd.Next(windowWidth - texture.Width);
        ypos = rnd.Next(windowHeight - texture.Height);

        // update sprite position with to xpos,ypos here.
    }

}

previousMouseState = currentMouseState;
```

Comment: Also, if your sprite happens to use a Rectangle to define its bounds then you can use the Rectangle.Contains method to see if mousePosition is within the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) are perfect for this.

The code you have above is probably called based on a timer/scheduler which fires an event.  You can change that into an [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) implementation through a call to the [`Observable.FromEvent` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707291%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Once you have that, you can then use the [LINQ operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242983%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) on the `IObservable<T>` to get the "windows" between mouse presses.  You would more than likely use the the [`TakeUntil` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229530%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) like so:

```
// Your initial observable.
var timerObservable = Observable.FromEvent(timer, "TimerFired");

// The button pressed.
var pressed = timerObservable.
    Where(t => Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed);

// The button not pressed.
var notPressed = timer.Observable.
    Where(t => Mouse.GetState().LeftButton != ButtonState.Pressed);

// Observe the not pressed until it is pressed.
// Make sure to repeat.
var pressed = notPressed.SkipUntil(pressed).Repeat();
```

You can then call the [`Subscribe` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.subscribe%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) and pass a delegate with your code which will be called while the button is pressed.

You can even replace the timer with a call to the [Observable.`Timer` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211753%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to generate your timer which you are waiting on.